# Does puppeteer load ads?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am currently building a web scraper for a website. However, I am having ethical concerns: The site provides a free service where they make money through ads.
Making the scraped content visible without ads therefore hurts the website I am scraping economically.
Does puppeteer load advertisements as a normal browser would and therefore generate revenue for the website providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. It emulates exactly what a browser would do.

Also, since Puppeteer doesn't click on the advertisements, the sites you're scraping won't get per-click revenue, just any possible per-impression revenue (unless the ad network detects you as non-human activity, in which case the site gets nada).

As an aside, since you're conscious about the ethicality of scraping the site, have you considered copyrights? The original site would likely own the copyright to the data you're scraping...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Concerning copyright: The whole project I am doing is sketchy when looking at it from a copyright standpoint, I am only using the data personally though. The website owner actually licenses the content I am accessing it and pays that via ad revenue. There is no way for me to detect whether my use of the site is actually flagged as non-human by the ad networks, right?

Comment: There probably isn't, no.